# If Package Isn't Available on NPM

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, bower

I'm trying to find best solutions for this. I've got a JS plugin that I need that doesn't seem to be available via npm. I usually `require()` my packages at the top of my `app.js` file so when it's spat out, it bundles all my js.

What best practices are there for when a plugin or package isn't available over npm or Bower. Are there any other ways to `require()` or is there a way around this?

I'd rather not have more than one js file on my site.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you just give the Path to your JS Plugin as parameter to `require()`, like in: `require('PATH/TO/MY/JSFILE.js')`?

Comment: Is that a generally good way to about it? Would it be better to `require()` from Bower? Is that even possible?

Comment: Are you coding Backend NodeJS or Frontend (with Browserify or something)?

Comment: Coding Frontend for a simple portfolio site. Figured I'd use Browserify for the bundling.

Comment: Well, it's even the first thing they do in the documentation, so it can't be all that wrong. Of course, your JSPlugin has to provide its functionality with a `module.exports` or `exports` before you require it. If it doesnt, you can add it.

Depending if its an open source lib, you could also think about wrapping it as require-module yourself and publishing it via npm (and/or bower) - then you could put it into your normale dependencies and require it without a path. ;)

Comment: Ahh, maybe that's why it's not currently working. How would I go about doing something like that?

Comment: Well, in your plugin file that you require, put whatever object you need as value for `module.exports`, or as property to `exports.MYNAME`. But if you don't know how all this works, you should maybe read first about `CommonJS` and more into how `Browserify` actually works.